# Create PSS clients connection for each user?

Tags: swarm

Good morning! I am looking at the PSS API checking the [erebos/pss.js](https://github.com/MainframeHQ/erebos/blob/master/examples/pss.js#L5-L6) example. I am slightly confused with the follow:

```
const alice = new PssAPI(createRPC('ws://127.0.0.1:8501'))
const bob = new PssAPI(createRPC('ws://127.0.0.1:8502'))
```

Do we have to create a new connection/port for each user? Having as reference a simple chat with ***n*** users. How would this even work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The default use case of `pss` is one sender/recipient *per* node. So in your case Alice would have a running node, Bob would have a different running node, and they each make websocket connections to their respective nodes.

You *can* create multiple [*subscriptions*](https://github.com/MainframeHQ/erebos/blob/master/examples/pss.js#L14)<sup>*</sup> on the same node (with the same topic), but both subscribers will then get the same messages. That means that distiguishing what is for who will have to be controlled in your application logic.

That being said, one running node will only have *one* single keypair for public key crypto, which is the same key as the swarm node is running on.

---

<sup>*<sub>I am unsure exactly how `erebos` maps to the actual calls in `pss` rpc calls. Via the RPC subscribe is only one action, but here it seems to be one for registering the topic and one for actually receiving messages.</sub></sup>